# Transient API and caching Plugins

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, transient, cache

Hello wordpress NINJAS....
I am crazy about transient api and I have implemented it in my theme.My question is

1. If I use transient api is it required caching plugin? (I hate plugins!!!)
2. If I use transient and caching ,how will be the result?
3. Can I use transient against caching plugin?
4. Is caching plugin and transient work on same principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some caching plugins that cache entire pages or sites in `.html` files so obviously anything generated on a page will be "cached" in that file. Other kinds of caching stores information in memory (RAM). The answer differs some according to which kind of caching you are talking about, but...

> If I use transient api is it required caching plugin? (I hate plugins!!!)

Don't hate plugins, just avoid the bad ones.

You don't have to use a caching plugin, ever, if you don't want to. Without a caching plugin you still get a kind of database-based caching.

> If I use transient and caching, how will be the result?

A caching plugin should store transient data persistently in memory (RAM) which allows faster access but obviously uses more RAM.

> Can I use transient against caching plugin?

No idea what this means.

> Is caching plugin and transient work on same principle?

Depends on the kind of plugin, I guess, but probably not. The transient API saves data to the database. By saving "heavy" work like a complex query or a remote HTTP request to the database you can get at it faster on subsequent requests. A caching plugin will save that data in RAM or a file which should likely be faster than PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Thank you indeed.one more question if i use transient api,shall I use caching plugin(w3 total cache)?

Comment: Use a caching plugin if you need one. What other answer is there?

Answer (score 3):

1. Transient API works in WordPress out of the box and does not require any plugin. However installing special object cache drop in can change it's back-end implementation. Typically for keeping data in memory rather than database and improving its performance.
2. Like rainbows and unicorns.
3. "against" is not clear in your question.
4. No. Full page caching plugins (assume that is kind you mean) typically store data in file system, so that it can be served by web server directly, bypassing WordPress.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst. I use against to mean that I will use transient for caching but not any plugin.And according to your opinion what is the best method?transient or plugin.